# Validating Radio Buttons on Submit

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events

I am trying to validate radio buttons on a competition, its multi-step so the radio buttons post the selection over to the entry form page.

Currently having trouble blocking the submission if there is nothing selected, got a script together but its not working.

HTML:

```
<form name="radioOptions" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<ul>
  <li><input type="radio" name="question" id="question1" value="questionL1">Miami</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="question" id="question2" value="questionL2">Washington</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="question" id="question3" value="questionL3">Rome</li>
  <li><button class="enterButton" name='submit' type='submit' /></button></li>
</ul>
</form>​
```

Script:

```
function validateForm() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("question");
    var formValid = false;

    var i = 0;
    while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
        if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true;
        i++;        
    }

    if (!formValid) alert("Must check some option!");
    return formValid;
}​
```

Also have it in a fiddle over [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/X8mHg/1/)

Some help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure if I did anything, but my exact code as I had it is suddenly working.

@Pow-Lan, using "javascript:" in place of return does not block the page from running the post function.

Thanks all the same guys.